# AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute '_Pickler'

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pickle

I tried to open a Flask app via Heroku and got this error:

> **AttributeError**: module *'pickle'* has no attribute _'*Pickler'*

I created `model.pkl` in a separate file:

```
model1 = Pipeline([
    ('CountVectorizer', CountVectorizer()), 
    ('TfidfTransformer', TfidfTransformer()),  
    ('KNeighborsClassifier',  KNeighborsClassifier()),
    ])
model1.fit(traindata_data, traindata_label)


import pickle 
pickle.dump(model1, open("model.pkl","wb"))
```

and load the pickle file from `app.py`:

```
model = pickle.load(open("./model.pkl","rb"))
```

Comment: Do you know what version of Python are you using via Heroku ?

Comment: It's using 3.6.0